# Read Integer From Sessions

Tags: c#, webforms

I am attempting to save the global variable Label1.Text to sessions and read it back in on page_load.  I passed the integer through here:

```
Session["points"] = TotalPoints.Label1;
```

And am attempting to read it back here. What am I doing wrong?

```
Label1.Text = (int)Session["points"];
```

All code is below:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = (string)Session["points"];
    }

    public class TotalPoints
    {
        public static int Label1;
    }

    public void Validations()
    {
        if (TextBox1.Text == "20")
        {
            Image5.Visible = true;
            Image6.Visible = false;
            TotalPoints.Label1 += 1;
        }
        else
        {
            Image5.Visible = false;
            Image6.Visible = true;
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Validations();
    }

    protected void newWindow(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int next = new Random().Next( 3 ) + 1;
        Response.Redirect(string.Format( "Question{0}.aspx", next ));
        Session["points"] = TotalPoints.Label1;
    }

</script>

<html>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="60px" ImageUrl="http://www.ixl.com/qgen_res/sets_of_objects/popsicles_100.gif" Width="107px" />
        <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" Height="60px" ImageUrl="http://www.ixl.com/qgen_res/sets_of_objects/popsicles_100.gif" Width="107px" />
        <asp:Image ID="Image3" runat="server" Height="60px" ImageUrl="http://www.ixl.com/qgen_res/sets_of_objects/popsicles_100.gif" Width="107px" />
        <asp:Image ID="Image4" runat="server" Height="60px" ImageUrl="http://www.ixl.com/qgen_res/sets_of_objects/popsicles_100.gif" Width="107px" />
        <br />
        How many popsicles are there?&nbsp; Count by fives. <br />
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="button1_Click"/>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Image ID="Image5" runat="server" Height="30px" ImageUrl="http://www.lookseeedit.com/resources/tick.jpg" Width="30px" Visible="False" />
        <asp:Image ID="Image6" runat="server" Height="30px" ImageUrl="http://star-w.kir.jp/grp/9/red-cross-wrong-i19.svg" Width="30px" Visible="False" />
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" /> </asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="/10"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Next Question" OnClick="newWindow"/>
    </form>
</html>
```

Comment: Why you are setting session value after redirecting? There is no logic in your function. Session value will not set after page redirects. Set it before redirecting to other page.    Also, you are setting Label1.Text = (int)Session["points"]; . Do you know Label1.Text will expect a string then why you are assigning 'int' to it?????

Answer (score 1):

No, you're not doing it right.

`Response.Redirect` occurs before `Session["points"]` is set inside of the `newWindow` function.

To start, you should rearrange those lines, but you should also call that function from somewhere too.